# How can I get GPS ONLY location in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, gps, location

I'm creating an application that users, members of the company where I work, can register points of interest on demand only pressing a button and writing a name and they are sent and stored to a server.

But I'm having trouble with the accuracy of the locations. I'm using `@ionic-native/geolocation` and even if I set `enableHighAccuracy` to `true`, I receive not precise positions. Some of them are meters further than the place where they were taken.

Is there any way to get geolocation only from GPS sensor?

I have been searching over google for hours, but no luck. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

This is the code where I'm getting the location on client side:

```js
obtenirPosicio(): Promise<Geoposicio> {
return new Promise<Geoposicio>((resolve, reject) => {

 const OPCIONS_GPS = {} as GeolocationOptions;
 OPCIONS_GPS.enableHighAccuracy = true;
 OPCIONS_GPS.maximumAge = 0;
 OPCIONS_GPS.timeout = 10000; // 10 segons de timeout per obtenir posicio GPS

 this.gps.getCurrentPosition(OPCIONS_GPS).then(res => {
  let nova_posicio = {} as Geoposicio;
  nova_posicio.lat = res.coords.latitude;
  nova_posicio.lng = res.coords.longitude;
  resolve(nova_posicio);
 }).catch(err => {
  reject(err);
 });

});
}
```

PS: I'm only aiming Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the user sets the Location Mode to "Device only" (i.e. GPS), when the Location Mode is "High Accuracy" the Android Location Manager will send through location data from both GPS and non-GPS sources, so some will be inaccurate Wifi/Bluetooth/cell triangulation positions.

However, you can filter these out by looking the `coords.accuracy` property of the result, which indicates the estimated accuracy of the position.
Decide what the minimum accuracy your are prepared to accept, then reject any that are less accurate than this.

For example:

```
obtenirPosicio(): Promise<Geoposicio> {
    return new Promise<Geoposicio>((resolve, reject) => {

        const MIN_ACCURACY = 20; // metres
        const OPCIONS_GPS = {} as GeolocationOptions;
        OPCIONS_GPS.enableHighAccuracy = true;
        OPCIONS_GPS.maximumAge = 0;
        OPCIONS_GPS.timeout = 10000; // 10 segons de timeout per obtenir posicio GPS

        this.gps.getCurrentPosition(OPCIONS_GPS).then(res => {
            // Reject udpate if accuracy is not sufficient
            if(!res.coords.accuracy || res.coords.accuracy > MIN_ACCURACY){
              console.warn("Position update rejected because accuracy of"+res.coords.accuracy+"m is less than required "+MIN_ACCURACY+"m");
              return; // and reject() if you want
            }

            let nova_posicio = {} as Geoposicio;
            nova_posicio.lat = res.coords.latitude;
            nova_posicio.lng = res.coords.longitude;
            resolve(nova_posicio);
        }).catch(err => {
            reject(err);
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I'd never read about the accuracy property and it's very helpful.

Comment: Despite, the user could never receive a good position with this solution. 
So I will need to show a message proposing to set the 'gps only' mode.

Thanks again!